# Почему в JS такой код 'j'==='a'||'i'||'e'||'o' возвращает символ 'i'

Tags: javascript

только начал изучать этот язык и заметил такую странную штуку, объяснение которой я не смог найти в интернете. 
Собственно такой код в консоли`'j'==='a'||'i'||'e'||'o'`   возвращает символ 'i' хотя поидее должен возвращать false. Хотя когда вторую половину кода беру в кавычки то значение возвращает правильно.

И вопрос номер два. Делал задачу на замену конкретных букв в строке на цифры. Можно ли как то по другому это реализовать, чтоб код было короче?или тот вариант который сделал я, самый правильный?

```html
var input = "it's dangerous business frodo";
var output = "";

for(i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
    if (input[i]==='a') {
        output+='4';
    } else if (input[i]==='i') {
        output+='1';
    } else  if (input[i]==='o') {
        output+='0';
    } else if (input[i]==='e') {
        output+='3';
    } else
   output+=input[i]
};

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Пожалуй, все просто: `||` вернёт первый thruthy объект (переменную). `'j'==='a'` - это false, поэтому пропускается. Далее `i` - она truthy, поэтому возвращается

Comment: "когда вторую половину кода беру в кавычки" - ??

Comment: Имею ввиду вот так 'j'===('a'||'i'||'e'||'o'), но я уже разобрался, почему так происходит благодаря комментарию выше. А по второму вопросу, может кто-то подсказать?

Comment: `input.replace(/[aioe]/g, function(match) { return ({a:4, i:1, o:0, e:3})[match]||match})` вместо перечисления букв в первой регулярке в принципе можно сделать просто `/./`, функция все равно если нет замены возвращает исходный символ на место, хотя возможно это медленнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var charMap = {
  'a': '4',
  'i': '1',
  'o': '0',
  'e': '3'
};

var input = "it's dangerous business frodo";
var output = input.split('').map(i => charMap[i] || i).join('');

console.log(output);
```